# mysqli,php store procedure not executing : getting Error

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost",
"username", "testpassword",
"dbname")or die('connection
problem');

/* check connection */ if
(mysqli_connect_errno()) {   
printf("Connect failed: %s\n",
mysqli_connect_error());    exit(); }

//if ($result = mysqli_query($link,
"CALL my_sqrt(Other,@out_value)")) {

$result = mysqli_query($link, "CALL  show_sp_test()");

$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",
$row_cnt);

/* close result set */   
mysqli_free_result($result); //}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
```

I got error like

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in sample-sp.php on line 19
>       Result set has 0 rows.
>       Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in sample-sp.php on line 24

but i change the stored procedure CALL to normal query working fine,

Tell me , is there any thing i should check /,

Is there any Bug in my snippet,

NOTE: IN MY SERVER MYSQLI ENABLED

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an error in the query.

You are not checking the return value of `mysqli_query` which returns `false` if it fails. You can get the reason for failing by calling `mysqli_error($link)` as:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "CALL show_sp_test()");
if(!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($link));
}
```

Comment: > Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /sample-sp.php on line 15
Invalid query:

Comment: yes , but error , still there in , what step should i take, only sp query not execution.